# PhoneGap Cordova 3.1.0 inAppBrowser EventListener not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm starting to use Cordova 3.1.0 now. I use command line to generate a project and then modify the existing code.
I copy and paste the following code from official website to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work. There are no alert. Then I added a button to try to fire the events.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
            ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
        });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">trigger</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This time, it works with second time. It means, it doesn't work when I click the button first time. But it works at the second time when I click the button. After that, I use console log inside the callback function to debug. The logs were not appeared at the first time (appeared at the second time and third, forth....).
I don't really know why this happened. I followed all steps from official website. Creating project, installing plugin, building and so on.
Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Hi. I just tried creating a new project and using your code above, and it seemed to work fine. I did `cordova create testIAB && cd testIAB && cordova platform add android && cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`` then I copied your first code chunk into `index.html` and ran `cordova build && cordova run` and it ran fine on my device; the start and stop errors both appeared the first time. Can you please test but run `adb logcat` and see if you get any errors on android's log? Also what OS are you building on? Finally what happens when you type `cordova --version`?

Comment: Many thanks. I tried everything but I failed. The following answer may be correct. I will try another version.

Comment: I am still having this issue in iOS, PG 3.3.0. Did you ever figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: I, too, have the same issue in iOS. kindly share the solution in case you have found it.

Comment: I'm using cordova 5.4.1 now, and for some reason(s) removing the in app browser plugin, re adding it, re building, then re running allowed the event to fire properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem with the last phonegap/cordova version 3.1.0.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/e5_5unC2fYs

Try an older version.

Comment: I just tried with the latest version that you'd get from `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` and there weren't any problems.

Comment: Can you put an example with the version and the dependencies? I tried with [the example of the documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) but I can't made it works either on cordova emulator nor on sdk emulator.

Comment: I am still having this issue in iOS, PG 3.3.0. Did you ever figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't.  It looks like my problem was only on the online emulator, but not in deployment (which I haven't checked but check appa post).  If you use it, use the eclipse configuration instead. It looks like the online emulator have still some bugs. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. On further investigation, I found that the events weren't firing in the emulator / browser, but fired fine on the Nexus 7 device that I do my testing on. Hope that helps!