# Loadstart event not triggered by inappbrowswer in phonegap 3.5

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-3, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am building an app using a combination of **angularjs** and **ionic**. I am running cordova version 3.5 and have the latest inAppBrowser cordova plugin 0.5.  I am taking some boilerplate code and having it run in a controller but the *loadstart* event never triggers.The crazy thing is the window still opens just fine.

```
$scope.call_google = function(){
       var authWindow = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
       authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
       console.log('loadstart fired');
       var url = event.originalEvent.url;
   });
}
```

Comment: Any chance you've missed including the cordova.js in the index.html?

Comment: also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591638/phonegap-cordova-3-1-0-inappbrowser-eventlistener-not-working

Comment: there are commenters still having the issue in 3.3 according to that thread, and a couple mention that the problem was happening in the emulator but not when run on a device.

Comment: on which device you checking the problem on?

Comment: After the browser I have used both an emulator and a device( Samsung G3 on kitkat) with remote debugging. Still no luck. Is there a way to output the cordova inappbrowser events to make sure they are working?